# Google Drive event stream

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

is there any Socket of **Google drive** that i can get from it a **Stream of the events** that the user execute such as:

- File moved
- Folder moved
- File created 
  and so on.

Comment: You might want to check [Detect Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) or [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push). Push notifications that inform your application when a resource changes while change list retrieve the list of changes for the currently authenticated user.

Comment: Take note that notifications do not contain details about the changes. Instead, they indicate that new changes are available. To retrieve the actual changes, poll the change feed as described in [Retrieving changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes#retrieving_changes).